# With Codeigniter, what's the difference if I wanted to set a method to private?

Tags: codeigniter

With `callback` functions that are within the same class, I can't set the following.

```
 private function check_valid_image
 {
 ...
 }
```

I can get it to work if I do the following.

```
 function _check_valid_image
 {
 ...
 }
```

By placing an underscore in front of the method name, is that the same as placing the word `private` in front?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a convention used with the form validation class for callbacks. It also makes that method not callable via the URL segments.

That being said, it is not the equivalent of making a method private, which has implications in how code can be run outside of the class.

Comment: Thanks, in conjunction to form validaitons, I can also use this convention to block direct access to my methods via URL segments?